# Can turning on Snapshot Isolation on Azure SQL have unwanted side effects if not actively used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure

We want to sync our Azure SQL database with an on-premises SQL database. The best way to do this seems to be Azure Db Sync.

I have this completely set up, but now when I want to start it, I get the following error:

> Sync failed with the exception "SqlException Error Code -2146232060 -
>   SqlError Number:3952,  Message: 
>       Snapshot isolation transaction failed accessing database 'myDb' 
>       because snapshot isolation is not allowed in this database. 
>       Use ALTER DATABASE to allow snapshot isolation.

I have googled a lot about snapshot isolation and I understand one of the effects of turning this on in that db writes will take a bit longer because it keeps versions of each row in a tempDb.

But the thing I'm most worried about is that our own queries will start having unwanted side effects because of the optimistic locking.

We have an ASP.net website and use ADO.net to access the database. If I make no changes at all, besides turning on snapshot isolation in the database with the ALTER DATABASE command, can I be sure then that our queries will keep on using the same locking they use at this moment?

So only the sql sync tool will actually use the snapshot isolation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON 
don`t set default isolation level

> If the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT option is set to OFF, you must
>   explicitly set the Snapshot isolation level for each session in order
>   to access versioned rows.

*So only the sql sync tool will actually use the snapshot isolation?*
yes, if sync set ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT